# How to get column name when calling sql stored procedure

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate3

I am newbie to hibernate .In my code i call the stored procedure like below.

```
Query query= sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("EXEC DASHBOARD_RESULT");
```

But this query only return the rows.I want the table header from the stored procedure.

How to get table column name from stored procedure results.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Where is your query?

Answer (score 0):

did you try `query.getResultList()` and iterate on it ?

inside the while cycle you can do:

```
Object[] singleBean = (Object[]) it.next();
```

and refer by col numbers with the right cast:

```
singleBean[i]
```

Comment: getResultList() is not exists.

Comment: Thats in JPA i guess. use javax.persistence.Query

Comment: with hibernate try query.list() is the same

Comment: but how to get the column name, not column value?